# USB-to-ETH not working on Bullseye

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Recently updated my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 from stretch to bullseye, and found lots have changed for example "Predictable Network Interface" which I was able to disable by adding 'net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0' to /boot/cmdline.txt.

But one other thing I ran into was USB-to-ETH is not being detected as interface on ifconfig

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Did "ifconfig -a" but did see it come up there, please let me know if there is the solution to this.

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.76-v7+ #1597 SMP Fri Nov 4 12:13:17 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Check `lsmod | grep ax88179`; if that does not show anything, try `sudo modprobe ac88179_178a`, then look and see if the interface shows up.  If you get "module not found", the problem is your kernel is out of sync with `/lib/modules` (it should contain a directory for  `5.15.76-v7+`.

Comment: "Recently updated my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 from stretch to bullseye" - i.e. you performed an unsupported upgrade and to make matters worse skipped intermediate versions. Save yourself a lot of trouble and do a fresh install (as recommended by Raspberry Pi Ltd.)